# how to write event.target statement for firefox?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a code to close the iframe when user clicks on the outside area. It works fine for chrome but not for firefox. I am still struggling to write the code in html and JS.

HTML :

```html
<div id="video-iframe-div" class="v-iframe-div-off" onclick="closesubpage();">
    <iframe src="" id="video-iframe" class="v-iframe-off" name="i-video">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

JS:

```js
function closesubpage() {
    var elementDiv = document.getElementById('video-iframe-div');
    var elementIframe = document.getElementById('video-iframe');
   if (event.target != elementIframe) {
     $('#video-iframe-div').prop('className','v-iframe-div-off');
     $('#video-iframe').prop('className','v-iframe-off');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because firefox **doesn't** have the `event` object flying around. In chrome it **does** have that's why your code works on Chrome.

To make it work for all browsers, always pass an explicit argument at the 1st position of the callback method like this

```
function closesubpage(evt, arg1, arg2,...) {
  // 'evt' is the event object and contains the target property.
  // You can name it whatever you want, even 'event'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I came across the fact that firefox does not recognize the "event.target"

Where'd you come across this? It certainly does, you just need to pass it as a function argument. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

You're using jQuery, so instead of using `onclick` on the element, you may as well attach a click handler with jQuery and keep your code cleaner:

```
$('#video-iframe-div').click(closesubpage);
```

Then you can improve your function call:

```
function closesubpage(event) {
    var elementIframe = $('#video-iframe');

    // If the target matches iframe, halt execution
    if (event.target === elementIframe) return;

    this.prop('className','v-iframe-div-off');
    elementIframe.prop('className','v-iframe-off');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Inline evnt through function :

```js
function closesubpage(event) {
console.log(event);
    // var elementDiv = document.getElementById('video-iframe-div');
    var elementIframe = document.getElementById('video-iframe');
   if (event.target != elementIframe) {
     $('#video-iframe-div').prop('className','v-iframe-div-off');
     $('#video-iframe').prop('className','v-iframe-off');
   }
}
```

```css
#video-iframe-div{cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="video-iframe-div" class="v-iframe-div-off" onclick="closesubpage(event)">
    <iframe src="" id="video-iframe" class="v-iframe-off" name="i-video">
    </iframe>
</div>
```